# Why does Keycloak Admin API's user query endpoint return an empty array

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

- I'm using a service-account with the `realm-management`/`query-users` role.
- I request a new access_token
- I send a query request to the Admin API users endpoint:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://example.com/admin/realms/REALM_NAME/users' \
        --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyTOKEN'
```

But I always receive an empty array: `[]` without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

After a day I finally played around with the roles:

- I also need the `realm-management/view-users` role to see the users, not just the `query-users` role.

*I was expecting the API to return a `403` or so when I'm missing the permissions.*